# How many lines should a function have at most?

Tags: coding-style

Is there a good coding technique that specifies how many lines a function should have ?

Comment: **42**. Someone had to say it

Comment: There is no standard number of lines but breaking down massive functions into smaller one-thing-doing functions will usually be better for readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  Lines of code is a pretty bad metric for just about anything.  The exception is perhaps functions that have thousands and thousands of lines - you can be pretty sure those aren't well written.

There are however, good coding techniques that usually result in fewer lines of code per function.  Things like DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and the Unix-philosophy ("Write programs that do one thing and do it well. Write programs to work together. Write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface." from Wikipedia).  In this case replace "programs" with "functions".

Comment: This. LOC is a worthless measurement. Quality is hard to measure formally (although it's pretty obvious to most when the code at hand is a TDWTF contender).

Comment: I think the last point on text streams doesn't quite apply to functions but good on everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it matters, who is to say that once a functions lengths passes a certain number of lines it breaks a rule.

In general just code clean functions easy to use and reuse.

Answer (score 1):

A function should have a *well defined purpose*. That is, try to create functions which does a single thing, either by doing the thing itself or by delegating work to a number of other functions.

Most functional compilers are excellent at inlining. Thus there is no inherent price to pay for breaking up your code: The compiler usually does a good job at deciding if a function call should really be one or if it can just inline the code right away.

The size of the function is less relevant though most functions in FP tend to be small, precise and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

There is a McCabe metric of Cyclomatic Complexity which you might read about at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

The metric measures how many tests and loops are present in a routine. A rule of thumb might be that under 10 is a manageable amount of complexity while over 11 becomes more fault prone.

I have seen horrendous code that had a Complexity metric above 50. (It was error-prone and difficult to understand or change.) Re-writing it and breaking it down into subroutines reduced the complexity to 8.

Note the Complexity metric is usually proportional to the lines of code. It would provide you a measure on complexity rather than lines of code.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity is sometimes a helpful metric, but there are times when it overly penalizes certain constructs. For example `if (foo==1) bar=1; if (foo==2) bar=4; if (foo==3) bar=9;` has a complexity of two, but rewriting it as `if (foo==3) bar=9; else if (foo==2) bar=4; else if (foo==1) bar=1;` would increase it to three. Still, it's worthwhile to note that some routines can get very long while having a cyclomatic complexity of one or two, and refactoring such routines is often not particularly useful.

Answer (score 1):

When working in Forth (or playing in Factor) I tend to continually refactor until each function is a single line! In fact, if you browse through the Factor libraries you'll see that the majority of words are one-liners and almost nothing is more than a few lines. In a language with inner-functions and virtually zero cost for calls (that is, threaded code implicitly having no stack frames [only return pointer stack], or with aggressive inlining) there is no good reason not to refractor until each function is tiny.

Comment: +1, however, I added ...except for, perhaps the inability to see the forest for the trees... in my head. A unit of work may actually be *too small* in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience a function with a lot of lines of code (more than a few pages) is a nightmare to maintain and test. But having said that I don't think there is a hard and fast rule for this.

I came across some VB.NET code at my previous company that one function of 13 pages, but my record is some VB6 code I have just picked up that is approx 40 pages! Imagine trying to work out which *If* statement an *Else* belongs to when they are pages apart on the screen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how many is a "page"? What page? A4 with 11pt Consolas? Am I missing something that I should obviously know?

Comment: @nuclear - when you press the page up or page down buttons - that's a page :-)

Answer (score 0):

The main argument against having functions that are "too long" is that subdividing the function into smaller functions that only do small parts of the entire job improves readability (by giving those small parts actual names, and helping the reader wrap his mind around smaller pieces of behavior, especially when line 1532 can change the value of a variable on line 45).

In a functional programming language, this point is moot:

- You can subdivide a function into smaller functions that are defined within the larger function's body, and thus not reducing the length of the original function.
- Functions are expected to be pure, so there's no actual risk of line X changing the value read on line Y : the value of the line Y variable can be traced back up the definition list quite easily, even in loops, conditionals or recursive functions.

So, I suspect the answer would be "no one really cares".

Comment: The point is not moot. It may be mitigated -- but is not moot: one can still have a big (or small) functions that "does too much". While being able to have nested functions is *very handy*, there are times when they should be *promoted out* in favor of being DRY (and thus shrinking the size of the function in question).

Answer (score 0):

I think a long function is a red flag and deserves more scrutiny. If I came across a function that was more than a page or two long during a code review I would look for ways to break it down into smaller functions.

There are exceptions though.  A long function that consists of mostly simple assignment statements, say for initialization,  is probably best left intact.

Answer (score 0):

My (admittedly crude) guideline is a screenful of code.  I have seen code with functions going on for pages. This is emetic, to be charitable.  Functions should have a single, focused purpose.  If you area trying to do something complex, have a "captain" function call helpers.

Good modularization makes friends and influences people.

Comment: If code can be written in such a way that it can be meaningfully examined a screenful at a time, that's generally a good thing.  On the other hand, if a method which is longer than that can't be subdivided into succinctly-describable pieces, writing separate functions for little pieces which whose most concise description would be the code they contain will simply mean that rather than having one slightly-overlong function to examine, one will have an even longer collection of methods that all need to be examined as a group.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the goal should be to minimize the amount of code that a programmer would have to analyze simultaneously to make sense of a program.  In general, excessively-long methods will make code harder to digest because programmers will have to look at much of their code at once.

On the other hand, subdividing methods into smaller pieces will only be helpful if those smaller pieces can be analyzed separately from the code which calls them.  Splitting a method into sub-methods which would only be meaningful in the context where they are called is apt to impair rather than improve legibility.  Even if before splitting the method would have been over 250 lines, breaking it into ten pieces which don't make sense in isolation would simply increase the simultaneous-analysis requirement from 250 lines to 300+ (depending upon how many lines are added for method headers, the code that calls them, etc.)  When deciding whether a method should be subdivided, it's far more important to consider whether the pieces make sense in isolation, than to consider whether the method is "too long".  Some 20-lines routine might benefit from being split into two ten-line routines and a two-line routine that calls them, but some 250-line routines might benefit from being left exactly as they are.

Another point which needs to be considered, btw, is that in some cases the required behavior of a program may not be a good fit with the control structures available in the language it's written in.  Most applications have large "don't-care" aspects of their behavior, and it's generally possible to assign behavior that will fit nicely with a language's available control structures, but sometimes behavioral requirements may be impossible to meet without awkward code.  In some such cases, confining the awkwardness to a single method which is bloated, but which is structured around the behavioral requirements, may be better than scattering it among many smaller methods which have no clear relationship to the overall behavior.